# Does the iOS Documents Directory need to be constructed every time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an iOS App that does a considerable amount of file operations. It's tedious to do `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]` every time to get the Documents directory's root.

Is it necessary?

Can I somehow store it in some kind of global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value will never change during a single run of the app so yes, it is safe to get it once on app startup and reuse the value throughout the app.

Don't ever persist the value though. It could be different the next time the app runs.